# SORT ONLY HIGHLIGHTED CELLS by column C & D

Tags: excel, vba

Ok......i did try to search and find the answer before posting this question, but no luck.

I am trying to create a macro/script that will sort columns A:Y  by column C (ascending) then column D (ascending).  I was able to easily create a macro to do this for cells A18:Y67 (entire workbook).  I am asking for help because i dont know how to modify this script to enable me to sort by varying rows and not the entire range.  The columns will always stay the same A:Y, however the row numbers can vary as sometimes i need to resort the sort (example A34:Y50  or A22:Y45).

(any help for this common core coder would be much appreciated)

Code is below

```
Sub HSSortByVendor()
'
' HSSortByVendor Macro
' Sort by column C & D
'

'
    Range("A18:Y67").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C18:C67"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D18:D67" _
        ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A18:Y67")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("H4:M4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered indirect() and building the relevant ranges?

Comment: Someone could write a procedure which you could e.g. use in the following way: `SortVendors ws, "A:Y", 34, 50, 3, 4` or just `SortVendors 34, 50` or ... etc. where `ws` is the worksheet object, "A:Y" the columns of the range, `34` the first row, `50` the last row, `3` the first column, and `4` the second column to be sorted. Why don't you share how (with which arguments, maybe `SortVendors "Hourly", "A:Y", 35, 50`) you were planning to call this procedure and someone might actually look into it.